# How to record user IP address to database?

Tags: meteor

I am working on a simple blog application using Meteor. However, users will be allowed to post anonymously. I want to record IP addresses of the senders along with their blog posts.

I could not find any way to access IP address. How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the user IP address in Meteor server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app,
        Fiber = Npm.require('fibers'),
        headers = {};

      app.use(function(req, res, next) {Fiber(function () {

          headers.remoteAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
          console.info(req.connection.remoteAddress);

          console.info(res.socket._peername);
          next();
        }).run();
      });
}
```