# Get client's ip at user creation in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm creating a custom sign-in/sign-up in Meteor because I need to check the email format and more importantly to add a recaptcha in the sign-up form, which requires the client's ip.

So I plan to verify the captcha in `Accounts.validateNewUser`, but I cant figure out how to get the client's ip here.
I read an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server) on how to do that, but it's not where I want to. I checked Meteor.default_server.sessions which contains all the sessions/sockets on the server. They contain information about headers, ips of all sockets. Each one has interesting stuff like:

```
pathname: "/sockjs/375/ibmrlwb2/xhr"
prefix: "/sockjs"
protocol: "xhr-polling"
remoteAddress: "127.0.0.1"
remotePort: 42009
```

But without knowing which socket is the current one, I cannot determine which ip of the current request is.

How can I know the current request url to the server? With that I can check with all the sockets on the server to infer the client's ip.

Or just simply how can I get the client's ip on the server?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the user IP address in Meteor server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of the [user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) package mentioned in the other answer.

Recent/upcoming versions of Meteor have [better support for managing connections](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection) as well as [built-in support for grabbing IP addresses](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/ca7a6929d74c4a4b05961dbbcfce4f522ddc15e4). Combined with the fact that [login hooks](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1815) were just merged into the `devel` branch today, you should be able to either handle this directly or use something that we'll add to the user-status package.

Feel free to open a pull request if there is something you need.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the client's ip can be done with the [user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) package.  You can either use package or look through the code and see how it is being done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into the code. Actually, we can have the current user's socket information (session ....) when in the `Meteor.publish` or `Meteor.method` context, not in `Accounts.validateNewUser` . If we inspect the socket information, we will have the user's ip address. The solution I took was: the client must give the socket id, then at the server side I loop through `Meteor.default_server.stream_server.open_sockets` to pick up the right socket and extract the client's ip. It's not a solid solution but helps me to move on.

Comment: I dont really know coffeescript, but is there any way of replicating this: `@_session.socket.remoteAddress` in Javascipt?

Comment: @Chet @ just means 'this', so that's this._session.socket.remoteAddress, which probably has the same scope problems