# How to access client IP address in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

This seems like a very basic question that doesn't have an elegant solution/answer out there.

How can I access the client (remote) IP address from (1) the server or (2) the client?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript

Comment: no idea what cgi-bin is or how to use it for this purpose... :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Florin mentioned, this is all pretty much integrated with Meteor now, as opposed to the dark ages when we had to do it ourselves. However, I've additionally wrapped it in a package that tracks all open connections and allows you to query for their IPs: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status. It also does a bunch of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 18):

Getting the client IP:

**Without a http request, in the functions you should be able to get the clientIP with:**

```
clientIP = this.connection.clientAddress;
//EX: you declare a submitForm function with Meteor.methods and 
//you call it from the client with Meteor.call().
//In submitForm function you will have access to the client address as above
```

**With a http request and using iron-router and its Router.map function:**

In the action function of the targeted route use:

```
clientIp = this.request.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Comment: Salut Florin, how about mentioning the question is a perfect duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server)?

Comment: I totally agree, at that time I wanted to place a comment with that instead of answering but I didn't have enough reputation points (posting a comment at  questions/answers that don't belong to you required 50p or more)

Comment: This is only available after version 0.7.1.1 for those who have applications running on older versions, like I had.

Answer (score 2):

On client

```
headers = {
    list: {},
    get: function(header, callback) {
        return header ? this.list[header] : this.list;
    }
}

Meteor.call('getReqHeaders', function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        headers.list = result;
    }
});
```

On server:

```
headers = {
    list: {},
    get: function(header) {
        return header ? this.list[header] : this.list;
    }
};

var app = typeof WebApp != 'undefined' ? WebApp.connectHandlers : __meteor_bootstrap__.app;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    reqHeaders = req.headers;
    return next();
});

Meteor.methods({
    'getReqHeader': function(header) {
        return reqHeaders[header];
    },
    'getReqHeaders': function () {
        return reqHeaders;
    },
});
```

Comment: This is obsolete now. The client IP is now offered via the core `clientAddress` - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package: https://github.com/gadicohen/meteor-headers. It gets headers on both client and server.

If you want to do it without a package, you can 'inspire' yourself from the code above, the thing to remember is that prior to 0.6.5 we used the 'hidden' `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` and post 0.6.5 it's recommended to use `WebApp.connectHandler` instead.

Comment: That is a very nice solution :)

Comment: didn't quite work on the server -- maybe I am doing it wrong: https://github.com/gadicohen/meteor-headers/issues/2