# Access client's IP address (not the load balancer's) from Meteor, with Modulus

Tags: meteor, ip-address, load-balancing, modulus.io

I have an https Meteor webapp hosted on [modulus.io](http://modulus.io). Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507998/how-to-access-client-ip-address-in-meteor) I have a server method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    printIP: function() {
        return this.connection.clientAddress;
    }
});
```

I call this from my browser console on the live site:

```
Meteor.call('printIP', function(err, ip) { console.log(ip); })
```

But this always returns Modulus's [load balancer](http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1700863-custom-domains)'s IP address, 54.236.216.66.

How can I access the client's IP address instead of the load balancer's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some experimentation I have found a solution:

```
Meteor.methods({
   printIP: function() {
      if (this.connection.httpHeaders && this.connection.httpHeaders['x-forwarded-for']) {
         return this.connection.httpHeaders['x-forwarded-for'];
      } else {
         return this.connection.clientAddress;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Note that the `X-Forwarded-For` header could be a comma-separated list (actually, a comma+space-separated list) of IP addresses, where the first address is the original client's.