# Meteor: How to get Ip address for custom tracking system

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I am very confused about ip addresses and headers. So I'm sorry if my question seems simple.

I have gone through the answers listed here:
[How to get the user IP address in Meteor server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server)

But I can't figure out how to make them work. For example, I am trying to use this:

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn) {
    console.log(conn.clientAddress);
});
```

But nowhere can I find where to place it.

If I place it on the client side it says Meteor.onConnection is undefined. If I place it on the server nothing happens. I don't think you run it on meteor.startup.

Is there someone could give me a hand in explaining where to use this code? Specifically if anyone has built a custom tracking system, that would be great. Do you store ips into database? or how to record for tracking purposes?

Any hint will help! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place the code anywhere on the server. e.g. in `server/main.js`. There is no need to call it from within `Meteor.startup`.
2. Start the app.
3. Open your browser to the appropriate address (e.g. http://localhost:3000) - this will cause a web client to connect and run the code from (1).
4. Look at your shell output (the shell you used to start the app - not the browser console) and you should see your local IP address (127.0.0.1) printed.

This should work in production as well, however if your app is served behind a proxy (e.g. nginx) you will need to add the appropriate commands to pass the user's IP to your app. For nginx, see [this post](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip/).