# Getting IP address and other connection information at Meteor Collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I know a way to get connection information is `this.connection` but this works at server-side, which requires context of server side. Some help at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server), but could not find the solution. As explained [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/what-goes-where/), Collection is shared both at client and server-side which is confusing me in how to get the server context or connection information at Meteor-Collection as I have used some methods in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap your code to [ensure it's running on the server](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isServer), something like:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    console.log(this.connection)
}
```

Comment: Even if I ensure it is not giving the context of server or connection properties.