# How to Retrieve IP address on Meteorjs?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How to Retrieve IP address on Meteorjs?. Any package is there?. Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the user IP address in Meteor server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843232/how-to-get-the-user-ip-address-in-meteor-server)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `mizzao:user-status` package to get the IP address of user. It is the standard package used to get such information about client-side user connection and status.

Install it with: `meteor add mizzao:user-status`

Then you can use the `UserStatus.connections` (in-memory) collection to get information for all connections on the server, in the following fields:

- `userId`: the user id, if the connection is authenticated.
- `ipAddr`:
  the remote address of the connection. A user logged in from different places will have one document per connection. **(This is the field you need)**

One thing, from their [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) on Atmosphere site:

> Note that to read client IP addresses properly, you must set the
>   HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT environment variable for your app, and make sure
>   that IP address headers are forwarded for any reverse proxy installed
>   in front of the app. See the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection) on this for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Install the http package:

```
meteor add http
```

Then use it:

```
var result = HTTP.get("https://api.ipify.org");

console.log(result.content)
```

Comment: how to get user ip address?

Comment: Have you searched for it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node for instance?